# How to save libdoc generated by robotframework-hub locally

Tags: python, robotframework

How I can save the generated documents of resource and library files using [robotframework-hub](https://github.com/boakley/robotframework-hub/wiki) as this expose only to [http:localhost:7070](http://localhost:7070).

Answer (score 0):

robotframework-hub doesn't have any support for that. The documents are generated on the fly.

However, the pages you see in robotframework-hub are generated by robot's [libdoc](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/2.1.2/tools/libdoc.html) tool, so you can use it to generate static files.

Answer (score 0):

*This is hack*
Using tool called `wget` we can download the the hosted files of robotframework-hub. Below are the steps to generate LibDoc and save them locally

```
python -m rfhub  folder_name
wget --mirror -nH -np -p -k -E -e robots=off  http://testhostedpagetobemirrored
```

**What this does do**
--mirror : Recursively download the entire site
-p : Download all necessary page requisites
-k : Convert the URL's to relative paths so we can host them anywhere

Note: On windows, Wget need to be installed, but on Mac and Linux, this comes by default with Mac OS. So the wget command can be run directly.